# Read address bar url from a flash site

Tags: javascript, flash, url

my dear friends..

I have a flash site, where when a user clicks on a link the page does not reload but the content changes with flash(like any normal flash site). So for example if user click on products page, the product page content is displayed, and the url in the address bar also changes from "domainname/index.aspx" to "domainname/index.aspx#/products"

I need to get this url from the address bar, and if i use "window.location.href" it returns "domainname/index.aspx". Does anyone know whether it is possible to read the url from the address bar which is changed by the flash.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Under ActionScript 3 (not sure about other versions), it is possible to invoke JavaScript functions in the client. You could use an [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) call to call a function that returns the URL from JavaScript (which should just be `window.location`).

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the URL (after the # character) is know as the hash and you can read it with `location.hash` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would give jQuery history plugin a try. It detects when the URL changes with a hash etc.

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

And you could simply send the Flash object the url when the jQuery history plugin detects a change :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I used the method to set the url in a js variable using flash, and use that variable to share the page. So i dont read from the flash loaded page, instead set it using flash !!